# Docker image build fails with alpine python and langchain[llms] but not with slim or base

Tags: python, docker, alpine-linux, langchain

I'm trying to build a docker container for my LLM application with `python:3.9-alpine` and `langchain[llms]==0.0.278`. I have to use alpine because of critical security vulnerability in the regular or slim version.

I get the following error when building which does not happen when I use slim or base image:

```
#8 70.06 INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of <Python from Requires-Python> to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
#8 70.07 INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of transformers to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
#8 70.12 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch<3,>=1; extra == "llms" or extra == "all" (from langchain[llms]) (from versions: none)
#8 70.13 ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch<3,>=1; extra == "llms" or extra == "all"
```

Is there a way to install missing libraries so that langchain is installed with no issues? I cannot use base or slim due to security concerns.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 python:3.9-alpine
WORKDIR /app
ADD requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt 
RUN pip3 --no-cache-dir install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /app
```

**requirements.txt**

```
transformers==4.33.2
psycopg2-binary==2.9.7
pgvector==0.2.2 
langchain[llms]==0.0.278 
loguru==0.7.2
boto3==1.28.39
```